# jQuery: Can't we assign jQuery(this) to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just practicing jQuery. So pardon me if this is a weird question.

**Question:** can we assign `jQuery(this)` to a variable?

**Explanation:**

I can assign various jQuery selectors to variables and then I can use those variables to call different jQuery functions.

For example

```
    $filterSwitch = jQuery('.filter-switch');

    $filterSwitch.click(function(e) {
       alert("Filter Button Clicked"); // This works without any problem
    });
```

On the other hand, I can't seem to use `jQuery(this)` after assigning it to a variable.

For example

```
    $filterSwitch = jQuery('.filter-switch');
    $current = jQuery(this);

    $filterSwitch.click(function(e) {
       $current.toggleClass("filter-on"); // This does not work
       jQuery(this).toggleClass("filter-on"); // This works
    });
```

Is this not allowed or is there any specific way to assign `jQuery(this)` to a variable?

Comment: Do you expect `$current` to contain the clicked element?

Comment: [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) should help

Comment: it does work to assign $(this) to a variable

Comment: `this` outside the `click handler` does not refers to `clicked` element. It refers to global context..

Comment: you say: `$filterSwitch = jQuery('.filter-switch');` which will put the jQuery element inside the variable. then you say `$current = jQuery(this);`. But `this` is not something yet. you would have to say `$current = $filterSwitch;`. but since this is just passes the value in another variable you can just say `$filterSwitch.click(function(e) {
       $filterSwitch.toggleClass("filter-on");
    });`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you need to remember that `this` refers to the context you are currently in.

So the first

```
$current = jQuery(this);
```

Could mean the body or something other than the second `this`.

The second `this` is in the context of the click method, and that context is set to `.filter-switch`

Hope that makes any sense :)

You can do this:

```
$filterSwitch = jQuery('.filter-switch');

$filterSwitch.click(function(e) {
   $filterSwitch.toggleClass("filter-on"); // This works for all elements with that class
   jQuery(this).toggleClass("filter-on"); // This works only for the one you're clicking atm
});
```

Just be aware that the first line, now refers to all elements that have the filter-switch class, and the second line only refers to the one you're handing at the moment.

Comment: Yeahhhhhhhhhh. That is the best explanation. Now I understand the problem. Thank you Sir :-)

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a **DOM Element**, jQuery sets the scope of the callback function to the element which is the subject of the callback.

Here `this` will be the clicked element here and will only be accessible using `this` keyword inside the callback of the handler.

```
$filterSwitch = jQuery('.filter-switch');
$current = jQuery(this);

$filterSwitch.click(function(e) {
  $current.toggleClass("filter-on"); // This does not work because when $current was assigned, `this` did not refer to the correct element.

  $newCurrent = jQuery(this); // Now `this` is the clicked element.
  $newCurrent.toggleClass("filter-on"); // This works
});
```